# Getting Auto updates causing 100% CPU utilization

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Have setup Google cloud SQL server in asia-south1 zone. Issue is we are getting auto updates triggered in GCP Cloud SQL during IST day hours by Google which is causing server to reach 100% CPU utilization and causing system downtime. 
Is there a way to block these updates during IST day hours and get it only in non critical (night) hours

Increased vCPUs from 1 to 2. However, that didn't help

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings?hl=en_US&_ga=2.119504649.-1438570463.1566804707&_gac=1.237815220.1572354460.EAIaIQobChMIirmG5cTB5QIVB0PTCh2bUQ3sEAAYASAAEgLwKPD_BwE#maintenance-timing-2ndgen)

> "If you do not set the Maintenance timing setting, Cloud SQL chooses
>   the timing of updates to your instance (within its Maintenance window,
>   if applicable)."

You can set your the Maintenance window DAY-TIME and choode Order of update "any", and the updates will be triggered during the Maintenance window.

Comment: Thanks. We have already set maintenance timing as follows

Preferred window :Sunday, 12:00 AM — 1:00 AM (UTC+5:30)

Order of update : Earlier.

However, updates are still happening at any time of day. 

Will changing Order of update to "any" stop updates outside maintenance window ?

Comment: Maintenance timing and maintenance window are two different things. Please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58727000/4539626

Comment: From my understanding changing Order of update to "any" stop updates outside maintenance window.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Cloud SQL best practices](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/best-practices), it is recommended to configure a maintenance window for your primary instance.

With maintenance window you can control when maintenance restarts will be performed. You can also specify whether an instance gets updates earlier or later than other instances in your project with [Maintenance timing](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#maintenance-timing-2ndgen).

**Maintenance window**

> The day and hour when disruptive updates (updates
>   that require an instance restart) to this Cloud SQL instance can be
>   made. If the maintenance window is set for an instance, Cloud SQL does
>   not initiate a disruptive update to that instance outside of the
>   window. The update is not guaranteed to complete before the end of the
>   maintenance window, but restarts typically complete within a couple of
>   minutes.

**Maintenance timing**

> This setting lets you provide a preference about the relative timing
>   of instance updates that require a restart. Receiving updates earlier
>   lets you test your application with an update before your instances
>   that get the update later.
>
> The relative timing of updates is not observed between projects; if
>   you have instances with an earlier timing setting in a different
>   project than your instances with a later timing setting, Cloud SQL
>   makes no attempt to update the instances with the earlier timing
>   setting first.

Answer (score 0):

Maintenance frequency is once in every few mounts. It means that in each few months database will be unresponsive once time while being maintained.

Is it possible to cancel maintenance or to make maintenance manually?